# Can not install WST on Eclipse 3.7.2

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to install WST on Eclipse 3.7.2 in order to be able to setup Tomcat server.

I tried to install new software from inside of Eclipse using the site http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/updates

It ends up with error:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Eclipse XML Editors and Tools SDK 3.1.1.v200907161031-7A228DXETAqLQFBNMuHkC8-_dRPY (org.eclipse.wst.xml_sdk.feature.feature.group 3.1.1.v200907161031-7A228DXETAqLQFBNMuHkC8-_dRPY)
  Missing requirement: Java EMF Model Utilities 2.0.201.v201001252130 (org.eclipse.jem.util 2.0.201.v201001252130) requires 'bundle com.ibm.icu [3.8.1.1,4.1.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: WST Common Core 3.1.1.v200908102300-7B77FZ6F7RZHKDIwRlOwUN (org.eclipse.wst.common_core.feature.feature.group 3.1.1.v200908102300-7B77FZ6F7RZHKDIwRlOwUN)
    To: org.eclipse.jem.util [2.0.201.v201001252130]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: WST Common Plug-in Developer Resources 3.1.1.v200908102300-7938c9xOCMxOeqvXiT-qoyvN9BV2 (org.eclipse.wst.common_sdk.feature.feature.group 3.1.1.v200908102300-7938c9xOCMxOeqvXiT-qoyvN9BV2)
    To: org.eclipse.wst.common_ui.feature.feature.group [3.1.1.v200908102300-7B5FRHDhdMOGnoekn4gtEJxSmPxV]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: WST Common UI 3.1.1.v200908102300-7B5FRHDhdMOGnoekn4gtEJxSmPxV (org.eclipse.wst.common_ui.feature.feature.group 3.1.1.v200908102300-7B5FRHDhdMOGnoekn4gtEJxSmPxV)
    To: org.eclipse.wst.common_core.feature.feature.group [3.1.1.v200908102300-7B77FZ6F7RZHKDIwRlOwUN]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse XML Editors and Tools SDK 3.1.1.v200907161031-7A228DXETAqLQFBNMuHkC8-_dRPY (org.eclipse.wst.xml_sdk.feature.feature.group 3.1.1.v200907161031-7A228DXETAqLQFBNMuHkC8-_dRPY)
    To: org.eclipse.wst.common_sdk.feature.feature.group [3.1.1.v200908102300-7938c9xOCMxOeqvXiT-qoyvN9BV2]
```

I tried to update Eclipse, it encountered some dependencies error:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: C/C++ Memory View Enhancements 8.3.0.201402142303 (org.eclipse.cdt.debug.ui.memory.feature.group 8.3.0.201402142303)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse Platform 3.7.0.I20110613-1736 (org.eclipse.platform.ide 3.7.0.I20110613-1736)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Debug Core 3.7.1.dist (org.eclipse.debug.core 3.7.1.dist)
    Debug Core 3.7.0.v20110518 (org.eclipse.debug.core 3.7.0.v20110518)
    Debug Core 3.7.1.v20111129-2031 (org.eclipse.debug.core 3.7.1.v20111129-2031)
    Debug Core 3.8.0.v20130514-0954 (org.eclipse.debug.core 3.8.0.v20130514-0954)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: C/C++ Memory View Enhancements 8.3.0.201402142303 (org.eclipse.cdt.debug.ui.memory.feature.group 8.3.0.201402142303)
    To: org.eclipse.cdt.debug.ui.memory.floatingpoint [1.0.0.201402142303]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Floating Point Memory Renderer 1.0.0.201402142303 (org.eclipse.cdt.debug.ui.memory.floatingpoint 1.0.0.201402142303)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.debug.core 3.7.100
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.7.2.dist-9nF7UHagFqn9pElwWhC90gLz-soEuSGYmtSeiRH (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.7.2.dist-9nF7UHagFqn9pElwWhC90gLz-soEuSGYmtSeiRH)
    To: org.eclipse.debug.core [3.7.1.dist]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.7.0.I20110613-1736 (org.eclipse.platform.ide 3.7.0.I20110613-1736)
    To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.7.2.dist-9nF7UHagFqn9pElwWhC90gLz-soEuSGYmtSeiRH]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to install eclipse kepler (4.3) as Java EE Version.

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/keplersr2

This version includes the WST.